# How to SUM a COUNT Column and display the answer in a Label

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have the following code

```
 Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT IdNumber, COUNT(DISTINCT date) AS 'Attendance' FROM record WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) GROUP BY idNumber ", cn)

    Dim i As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While i.Read
        Label1.Text = i("SUM(Attendance)")
        i.Close()
    End While
```

I need to display the COUNT Column SUM in a label, but when i run the code i get the following error:

> 'Could not find specified column in results: SUM(Attendance)'

The COUNT Column(Attendance) is generated within the code to get specific COUNT of items in table record in a specific date period and returns the following:

```
+----------+------------+
| idNumber | Attendance |
+-----------------------+
| 88383    | 4          |
| 64785    | 2          |
+-----------------------+
```

and now i want to SUM those specific items and display them in a table like below:

Label = 6

Comment: Havinv the actual code that generated the column would have helped. I have a feeling that you column just doesn't exist if you did it through code. It'll only be available if it is generated by the server first. Eother by already being calculated in MySQL or by being part of a sub-query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to sum up all distinct date per IdNumber, you don't need to select idNumber then do a sub-query to sum up all attendance.

```
SELECT SUM(Attendance) as Label
from (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT date) AS 'Attendance' 
    FROM record 
    WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) 
    AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
    GROUP BY idNumber
     );

 Result:
   Label
   6
```

Comment: That worked great, it was just missing an alias at the end, but thank you.